# Can't Insert or update values to dynamically created textbox into SQL Server database Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have created textbox and label dynamically, which can automatically increased if I increase the rows of the database. But now I want to insert or update values into textbox to store data in the database.

Here is my code...

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
        //string cmText = "select ProductId,ProductName,UnitPrice from tblProduct";
        string cmText = "Select Count(ProductId) from tblProduct";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmText, con);

        con.Open();
        Int32 count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        cmText = "select ProductId,ProductName,UnitPrice from tblProduct";

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(cmText, con);

        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
        {
           //code for dynamically created textbox and label
        }
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        //string cmText = "select ProductId,ProductName,UnitPrice from tblProduct";

        con.Open();

        //TextBox tx = (TextBox) Controls.Find(myTextbox[0], true)[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.Controls[i] is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox myTextbox = (TextBox)this.Controls[i];
                string value = myTextbox.Text;

                string cmText = "insert into table tblProduct (UnitPrice) values('" + myTextbox.Text + "')";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmText, con);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is [the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYMA3.png)

**Edit:** Here is the code for creating textbox dynamically...

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{

    string cmText = "Select Count(ProductId) from tblProductInventory";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmText, con);
    con.Open();
    Int32 count = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    int i = 1;
    cmText = "select ProductId,ProductName,UnitPrice from tblProductInventory";
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(cmText, con);
    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
    {
        int y = 50;
        Label myLabel = new Label();
        TextBox MyTxt = New TextBox();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            myLabel = new Label();
            myLabel.Location = new Point(88, y);
            myLabel.Name = "txtVWReadings" + i.ToString();
            myLabel.Size = new Size(173, 20);
            myLabel.TabIndex = i;
            myLabel.Visible = true;
            myLabel.Text = rdr[1].ToString(); 
            y += 25;
            this.Controls.Add(myLabel);


            MyTxt.Text = rdr[2].ToString(); 
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you creating the textbox and label?

Comment: in winform ....

Comment: I was referring to your code. It doesn't appear you are creating any text boxes. Please post the code.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Hey @BlueeandRed I think you only need to have a update command instead of insert because records already exist in the DB. And if You wanted to insert a new record than probably you wanted to add new controls on the form. Where you have give value to the label and textbox and only newly added controls value will get inserted. Do you think I am right??

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you are creating the SqlCommand object but it is not getting executed. You need to add ExecuteNonQuery().

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        //string cmText = "select ProductId,ProductName,UnitPrice from tblProduct";

        con.Open();
        //TextBox tx = (TextBox) Controls.Find(myTextbox[0], true)[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.Controls[i] is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox myTextbox = (TextBox)this.Controls[i];
                string value = myTextbox.Text;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) 
                {
                string cmText = "insert into tblProduct (UnitPrice) values('" + myTextbox.Text + "')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmText, con);
                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if(result > 0)
                   {
                       //successful
                   }
                else
                 {
                    //fail
                 }
               } 
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I got System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll running your edit at int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Right... the insert query itself is incorrect. "insert into tblProduct (UnitPrice) values". No table keyword. Missed from me too. Updated the answer.

Comment: Now , value inserted but it automatically creates some null rows.

Comment: You are firing the insert query in a loop and it will run for every textbox in the form i.e. 4 in your case. So it inserts four row in database even for empty text boxes. You may want to check non emptiness before firing your insert query.

Comment: edited the the answer. However you could easily get it in Google.com

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect answer. But there are issues with the approach you have taken. What I understand is you cannot run a insert command in this situation, because to run a Insert Command or to add a new record to your database means you wanted to add a new Product to your database for that you need to add new controls to your form first.

Than you need to identify the newly added controls and then run a insert command for that product.

So I believe you need to update the values of the Products you already have in the Database. But then again there is a problem if you run a Update command is that you should know which ProductID or ProductName has to be updated before updating the Price of the Product.

The code of the Update Button almost looks like this

On Click of Update Button

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs)) using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{ 
    cmd.CommandText = "Update tblProduct SET UnitPrice =@paramunitprice WHERE ProductName = @paramproductname";
    con.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        if (this.Controls[i] is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox myTextbox = (TextBox)this.Controls[i];
            string txtvalue = myTextbox.Text;
            string lblvalue = //The Corresponding Label value to find which UnitPrice has to change.
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramunitprice", txtvalue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramproductname", lblvalue);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

But the biggest problem is to find the `lblvalue` corresponding to the textbox. That means if you have updated the value of Banana it should not update apple.

So I would recommend you to use [DataGridView](https://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial) for this kind of scenario where you will have updated record in the grid. You can update it and Insert new records as well. Believe me its lot easier than what you are trying to do.